# MySQL SUM(column) + (SUBQUERY WITH SUM)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query that adds up points for a team. The points are added up by doing SUM on a column + a SUM from another table with the same team-id. I try to write it like this:

```
SELECT 
    k.id, 
    s.fylke, 
    s.Kommune, 
    s.Skolenavn, 
    k.schoolid, 
    k.number, 
    k.letter, 
    SUM(e.amount) + (SELECT SUM(poeng) FROM oppdrag WHERE klasseid=k.id ) AS poeng 
FROM skoler AS s, klasser AS k, etappe AS e 
WHERE s.id=k.schoolid AND k.id=e.klasseid AND e.year='2016'
GROUP BY k.id 
ORDER BY poeng
```

The problem is that, when I write it in this fashion, it gives correct amount of points if the team has an entry in table "oppdrag" otherways it just returns NULL as points (poeng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your subquery returns `NULL`, this will result in trying to sum a number with `NULL`, which gives `NULL` back.

To fix this, you can try using the `IFNULL` function, that will replace it with a `0` if the query doesn't return any values:

```
SELECT 
    k.id, 
    s.fylke, 
    s.Kommune, 
    s.Skolenavn, 
    k.schoolid, 
    k.number, 
    k.letter, 
    SUM(e.amount) + IFNULL((SELECT SUM(poeng) FROM oppdrag WHERE klasseid=k.id ), 0) AS poeng 
FROM skoler AS s, klasser AS k, etappe AS e 
WHERE s.id=k.schoolid AND k.id=e.klasseid AND e.year='2016'
GROUP BY k.id 
ORDER BY poeng
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid that subquery from your select statement, it's going to kill your performance. Also, you should really be using the correct join syntax (the style you're using is ancient). Try something like this;

```
SELECT 
    k.id, 
    s.fylke, 
    s.Kommune, 
    s.Skolenavn, 
    k.schoolid, 
    k.number, 
    k.letter, 
    SUM(e.amount) + ISNULL(SUM(od.poeng),0) AS poeng 
FROM skoler AS s
INNER JOIN klasser AS k 
    ON s.id = k.schoolid
INNER JOIN etappe AS e 
    ON k.id = e.klasseid
LEFT JOIN oppdrag od 
    ON od.klasseid = k.id
WHERE e.year='2016'
GROUP BY k.id 
ORDER BY poeng
```

Comment: You are probably correct. It looks better to write with proper JOINS. But it looks like the two style of queryies use the same amout of time to run, so I'm not so sure it kills performance.

Comment: it would all depend upon how much data you're processing. The subquery with the select is going to be called once for each row of the result set. If you join then it'll just be called the once in total.

Comment: I have a feeling that the subquery doesn't run once per row. I've used subqueries like this many times with nice performance. I think the query is optimised before it is executed.  But I agree, your syntax is better and has more control over what is happening, mine is sloppy :)

Answer (score 1):

First, learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` with `ON`.

Then, you can solve your problem by including the subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT ske.*, ske.amount + COALESCE(od.amount, 0) as poenb
FROM (SELECT k.id, s.fylke, s.Kommune, s.Skolenavn, k.schoolid, 
             k.number, k.letter, SUM(e.amount) as amount
      FROM skoler s JOIN
           klasser k
           ON s.id = k.schoolid JOIN
           etappe e 
           ON k.id = e.klasseid AND e.year = '2016' 
      GROUP BY k.id 
     ) ske LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT od.klasseid, SUM(od.poeng) as amount
      FROM oppdrag od
      GROUP BY od.klasseid
     ) od
     ON od.klasseid = k.id
ORDER BY poeng;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit `JOIN` syntax. Also, include all columns that aren't aggregated in `GROUP BY` clause. Just because MySQL doesn't yield an error it doesn't mean that it's advisable to do it the way you did it. Not including all columns that aren't aggregated in a group by means picking random values.

```
SELECT 
    k.id, 
    s.fylke, 
    s.Kommune, 
    s.Skolenavn, 
    k.schoolid, 
    k.number, 
    k.letter, 
    COALESCE(SUM(e.amount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(o.poeng), 0) AS poeng 
FROM skoles AS s
INNER JOIN klasser AS k ON s.id = k.schoolid
INNER JOIN etappe AS e ON k.id = e.klasseid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT klasseid, SUM(poeng) AS poeng FROM oppdrag ) AS o ON o.klasseid = k.id
WHERE e.year = '2016'
GROUP BY k.id, s.fylke, s.Kommune, s.Skolenavn, k.schoolid, k.number, k.letter
ORDER BY poeng
```